# Replace $0.00 text in CART of wooCommerce 3.0

Tags: wordpress, replace, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to replace $0.00 text to $100 in CART of wooCommerce - Just the text of it.

I tried several hooks but none of it is working in Woocommerce 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', array ($this, 'your_function' ), 10, 1 );

public function your_function($cart){
    foreach ( $cart->cart_contents as $key => $value ){
        if(isset($value)){
        $value['data']->set_price(100);
       }
    }
}
```

This is the hook **"woocommerce_before_calculate_totals"** which can be used for changing the price in cart page. You have to use **"set_price"**(for Woocommerce version 3.0.0) function for setting the cart price